# Kotlin sealed class with data classes not recognizing subclass

Tags: kotlin, generics, sealed

I am trying to define a Kotlin sealed class which consists of a number of data classes. The latter are used to define data transfer objects (DTO) representing the mySQL tables in a room database. I introduced the sealed class to generalize the different DTOs and be able to refer to them all by their supertype (DTO - the common properties each specific DTO has, eg. "id", etc.).

This compiles alright, but I don't think Kotlin understands that the data classes are the "subclasses" of the sealed class - no matter whether I defined them all in the same file as the sealed (parent) class, or - the preferred choice - in the same package... both options should be valid choices, according to the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#location-of-direct-subclasses).

Any idea, where I'm going wrong here? Thanks.

**Code:**

```
package com.tanfra.shopmob.smob.data.local.dto

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
import com.tanfra.shopmob.smob.data.local.utils.*

/**
 * supertype, common to all DTO types - generic part of any DTO class
 * (properties declared abstract --> implementation delegated to inheriting concrete class)
 */
sealed class Dto {
    abstract val id: String
    abstract var itemStatus: SmobItemStatus
    abstract var itemPosition: Long
}

@Entity(tableName = "smobGroups")
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
data class SmobGroupDTO(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "groupId") override val id: String = "invalid smob group entry",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupItemStatus") override var itemStatus: SmobItemStatus = SmobItemStatus.NEW,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupItemPosition") override var itemPosition: Long = -1L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupName") var name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupDescription") var description: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupType") var type: GroupType = GroupType.OTHER,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupMembers") var members: List<String> = listOf(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupActivityDate") var activityDate: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupActivityReps") var activityReps: Long = 0,
) : Dto()

@Entity(tableName = "smobLists")
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
data class SmobListDTO(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "listId") override val id: String = "invalid smob list id",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listItemStatus") override var itemStatus: SmobItemStatus = SmobItemStatus.NEW,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listItemPosition") override var itemPosition: Long = -1L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listName") var name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listDescription") var description: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listItems") var items: List<SmobListItem> = listOf(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listMembers") var members: List<String> = listOf(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listLifecycleStatus") var lcStatus: SmobItemStatus = SmobItemStatus.OPEN,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "listLifecycleCompletion") var lcCompletion: Double = -1.0,
) : Dto()

@Entity(tableName = "smobProducts")
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
data class SmobProductDTO(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "productId") override val id: String = "invalid smob product id",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productItemStatus") override var itemStatus: SmobItemStatus = SmobItemStatus.NEW,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productItemPosition") override var itemPosition: Long = -1L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productName") var name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productDescription") var description: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productImageUrl") var imageUrl: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productCategoryMain") var categoryMain: ProductMainCategory = ProductMainCategory.OTHER,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productCategorySub") var categorySub: ProductSubCategory = ProductSubCategory.OTHER,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productActivityDate") var activityDate: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productActivityReps") var activityReps: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productInShopCategory") var inShopCategory: ShopCategory = ShopCategory.OTHER,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productInShopName") var inShopName: String = "dummy shop",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "productInShopLocation") var inShopLocation: ShopLocation = ShopLocation(0.0, 0.0),
) : Dto()

@Entity(tableName = "smobShops")
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
data class SmobShopDTO(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "shopId") override val id: String = "invalid smob shop id",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopItemStatus") override var itemStatus: SmobItemStatus = SmobItemStatus.NEW,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopItemPosition") override var itemPosition: Long = -1L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopName") var name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopDescription") var description: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopImageUrl") var imageUrl: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopLocationLatitude") var locLat: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopLocationLongitude") var locLong: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopType") var type: ShopType = ShopType.INDIVIDUAL,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopCategory") var category: ShopCategory = ShopCategory.OTHER,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopBusiness") var business: List<String> = listOf()
) : Dto()

@Entity(tableName = "smobUsers")
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns
data class SmobUserDTO(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "userId") override val id: String = "invalid smob user id",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userItemStatus") override var itemStatus: SmobItemStatus = SmobItemStatus.NEW,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userItemPosition") override var itemPosition: Long = -1L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userUsername") var username: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userName") var name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userEmail") var email: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userImageUrl") var imageUrl: String? = ""
) : Dto()
```

The reason, I believe Kotlin didn't make the desired connection between the sealed class and the data classes (= subclasses) is that it still asks me for an "else" branch in "when" expressions which act upon the members of the sealed class:

```
package com.tanfra.shopmob.smob.data.net.nto2dto

import com.tanfra.shopmob.smob.data.local.dto.*
import com.tanfra.shopmob.smob.data.net.nto.*
import com.tanfra.shopmob.smob.data.repo.ato.Ato


// ATO --> DTO
fun <DTO: Dto, ATO: Ato> ATO._asDatabaseModel(d: DTO): DTO? {

    return when (d) {
            is SmobGroupDTO -> {
                SmobGroupDTO(
                    id = (this as SmobGroupNTO).id,
                    itemStatus = this.itemStatus,
                    itemPosition = this.itemPosition,
                    name = this.name,
                    description = this.description,
                    type = this.type,
                    members = this.members,
                    activityDate = this.activity.date,
                    activityReps = this.activity.reps,
                ) as DTO
            }
        is SmobListDTO -> {
            SmobListDTO(
                id = (this as SmobListNTO).id,
                itemStatus = this.itemStatus,
                itemPosition = this.itemPosition,
                name = this.name,
                description = this.description,
                items = this.items,
                members = this.members,
                lcStatus = this.lifecycle.status,
                lcCompletion = this.lifecycle.completion,
            ) as DTO
        }
        is SmobProductDTO -> {
            SmobProductDTO(
                id = (this as SmobProductNTO).id,
                itemStatus = this.itemStatus,
                itemPosition = this.itemPosition,
                name = this.name,
                description = this.description,
                imageUrl = this.imageUrl,
                categoryMain = this.category.main,
                categorySub = this.category.sub,
                activityDate = this.activity.date,
                activityReps = this.activity.reps,
                inShopCategory = this.inShop.category,
                inShopName = this.inShop.name,
                inShopLocation = this.inShop.location,
            ) as DTO
        }
        is SmobShopDTO -> {
            SmobShopDTO(
                id = (this as SmobShopNTO).id,
                itemStatus = this.itemStatus,
                itemPosition = this.itemPosition,
                name = this.name,
                description = this.description,
                imageUrl = this.imageUrl,
                locLat = this.location.latitude,
                locLong = this.location.longitude,
                type = this.type,
                category = this.category,
                business = this.business,
            ) as DTO
        }
        is SmobUserDTO -> {
            SmobUserDTO(
                id = (this as SmobUserNTO).id,
                itemStatus = this.itemStatus,
                itemPosition = this.itemPosition,
                username = this.username,
                name = this.name,
                email = this.email,
                imageUrl = this.imageUrl,
            ) as DTO
        }
        else -> null

    }  // when(DTO) ... resolving generic type to concrete type

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be _asDatabaseModel(d: Dto): Dto?_ instead of _asDatabaseModel(d: DTO): DTO_?

Comment: Hi Lukas, declaring the call-up parameter "d" as "Dto" would fix the when issue, making Kotlin understand that this is indeed the sealed class and that no "else" is needed to be exhaustive. However, this also means to change the calling site from "smobItemATO._asDatabaseModel(dummySmobItemDTO)" to "smobItemATO._asDatabaseModel<DTO, ATO>(dummySmobItemDTO)", as Kotlin no longer can infer the (generic) type from the call-up parameter. The return type needs to be cast to "DTO" for my generic repository class to work - changing it to "Dto" means that I will then have to cast it at the call site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by your use of generics on the method signature :

```
fun <DTO: Dto, ATO: Ato> ATO._asDatabaseModel(d: DTO): DTO?
```

There's a good thread on Reddit which is very like your example. See here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/ei8zh5/kotlin_requires_else_branch_in_when_statement/

So, to solve your problem, just change the method signature to return a type of `DTO` not `DTO?`

It's almost as if the compiler is forgetting that the DTO is a sealed class when you make it a generic parameter, so you need an exhaustive check.

As you as using `is` in a `when` statement Kotlin will smart cast the DTO to the right type anyway, so no need for the generic argument.

Here's a cut down example based on your code that works without the else:

```
package paul.sealed

sealed class DTO {
    abstract val id: String
}

data class SmobGroupDTO(override val id: String = "invalid smob user id", val name: String = "") : DTO()
data class SmobListDTO(override val id: String = "invalid smob user id", val name: String = "") : DTO()

fun main() {

    fun processDTO(dto: DTO): String {

        return when (dto) {
            is SmobGroupDTO -> "Group"
            is SmobListDTO -> "List"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for you comments and the link to the reddit thread. It seems to me though, that the stripped-down example you provided does away with the generic types and, as such, is but a mere "regular use case" of sealed class handling with when. I admit, the generic code I provided might be confusing, as I'm using capitalized DTO to denote the generic type and the non-capitalized "Dto" for the sealed class. I think, my example is similar to the "reddid example 3.5" - reading through the comments, it appears to be an open issue at jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19645)

Comment: It also mentions a workaround - adding an "unnecessary cast" in the argument of the when statement informs IntelliJ IDEA / the compiler that this generic type belongs to a sealed class:  so, instead of "when(d) {...}" I can use "when(d as Dto) {...}" which makes the code compile. I wonder though, if this is the best that can be done. The above mentioned issue appears to have been open for 2 years - not sure if it will ever be fixed...

Comment: Yes, there are definitely cases where you'd think that the when should be exhaustive without the else.

But for your case, can you just do away with the generics like I did and make it work like that ?

Comment: By the way - I now did away with the "?" at the return type as, without the else branch, I do not need to introduce a "null", but (exhaustively) return valid types. This was my main concern all along and with the above described workaround I can at least avoid a whole lot of exception handling (to react to the "null" from the else branch). So, thanks for providing the reddid link - it helped me finding this workaround.

Comment: Cool, can you upvote my answer if you found it useful - thanks,.

Comment: I think I cannot do away with the generics, as this is used in a generic repository class in which I need this conversion to be generic. In each concrete instance of this repository, call-up parameter is one of the concrete types (eg. SmobGroupDTO)... so I cannot simply use the (concrete) sealed type "Dto" instead.